# How to find $\frac{x}{y}$?

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

Let $x=\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{180}\left(\cos{\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{180}\right)}+2\right)$ and $y=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{89}\binom{180}{2n+1}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n$.
How to find $\frac{x}{y}$ ?

I have no idea to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $1+\cos2t=2\cos^2t.$

Comment: You can find the solution here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c9918h1168484_how_to_find_fracxy_