# Combinatorics and trigonometry identity

Tags: combinatorics, trigonometry

Prove the following:

$\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^{180}\left(\cos{\left(\dfrac{n\pi}{180}\right)}+2\right)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{89}\binom{180}{2n+1}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^n$.

We can state this as $\displaystyle \binom{180}{1}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^0+ \binom{180}{3}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^1+\cdots+\binom{180}{179}\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^{89} = \left(\cos\left(\dfrac{\pi}{180}\right)+2\right)\left(\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi}{180}\right)+2\right) \cdots \left(\cos\left(\dfrac{180\pi}{180}\right)+2\right)$

The problem I am encountering is that there is no general result we can prove about this for $n$ it seems. I tried using induction on $n$ to prove this but it fails for the base case. Also, combinations and cosines seem unrelated, so how could I prove the equation is true?

Comment: You tried re-writing the cosine function as a complex exponential? Just an idea, Idk if it will work. And every time I see some product equal to some summation Dirichlet series comes to my mind. You can see what are the divisors of 180, or see if you can write the RHS using binomial series combined with summation by parts. Just sending random ideas.

Comment: [Duplicate of this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1551749).

Comment: You can find the solution here: http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c9918h1168484_how_to_find_fracxy_

Answer (score 3):

First rewrite $\cos(x)$ as $\cos(x) = \dfrac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$. Then we also have $\dfrac{1}{2}(4+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) = \cos(x) + 2$. We can factorize the left-hand side of the last equality as $\dfrac{1}{2}(4+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left(a+\dfrac{e^{ix}}{a}\right)\left(a+\dfrac{e^{-ix}}{a} \right)$ where $a^2+\dfrac{1}{a^2} = 4$. This gives four solutions for $a$, so I will pick the positive one, which is $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}}$. Now notice that this allows us to evaluate the left-hand side of $(1)$. We have that $\dfrac{1}{2a^2}(a^2+e^{ix})(a^2+e^{-ix}) = \cos(x) + 2$. Then make the substitution $x = \dfrac{n\pi}{180}$ to get that $$\dfrac{1}{2a^2}(a^2+e^{\frac{in\pi}{180}})(a^2+e^{-\frac{in\pi}{180}}) = \cos \left ( \dfrac{n\pi}{180} \right) + 2,$$ which we can use to rewrite the left-hand side of $(1)$. Thus, $$\displaystyle \prod_{n=1}^{180} \left (\cos \left( \dfrac{n\pi}{180} \right) + 2 \right) = \prod_{n=1}^{180} \left(\dfrac{1}{2a^2}(a^2+e^{\frac{in\pi}{180}})(a^2+e^{-\frac{in\pi}{180}}) \right).$$ Then see that the numbers $e^{\frac{in\pi}{180}}$ for $n = -180,-179,\ldots,-1,0,1,\ldots,179$ are the roots of the equation $x^{360} = 1$. Now, we see that $$\prod_{n=1}^{180} \left(\dfrac{1}{2a^2}(a^2+e^{\frac{in\pi}{180}})(a^2+e^{-\frac{in\pi}{180}}) \right) = \dfrac{1}{2^{180}a^{360}}\dfrac{(a^{720}-1)(a^2-1)}{a^{2}+1}.$$ To calculate the RHS, we see that $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 0}^{89} \binom{180}{2n+1} \left( \dfrac{3}{4} \right)^n = \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{180} - \left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{180}}{\sqrt{3}}.$ It remains to show that $$\dfrac{1}{2^{180}a^{360}}\dfrac{(a^{720}-1)(a^2-1)}{a^{2}+1} = \dfrac{\left(1+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{180} - \left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)^{180}}{\sqrt{3}}.$$ To see this, first observe that $1-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2a^2}$, $a^2 = 1+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, and $$\dfrac{1}{2^{180}a^{360}}\dfrac{(a^{720}-1)(a^2-1)}{a^{2}+1}=\left[\left(\dfrac{a^2}2\right)^{180}-\left(\dfrac1{2a^2}\right)^{180}\right]\cdot\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}.$$ Then finally we see that $\dfrac{a^2-1}{a^2+1} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, proving the desired result.